# padrino && websockets

Tags: ruby, sinatra, websocket, eventmachine, padrino

i'm looking for a way to open and use websockets from within a [Padrino](http://padrinorb.com) application. i know Padrino works with a single thread but i'm looking for a way to open websockets and share variables between its "onopen" "onclose" "onmessage" methods and Padrino controllers.

any idea how it's done ?

links i looked into:

[Examples of Eventmachine usage with Padrino and Sinatra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999430/any-success-with-sinatra-working-together-with-eventmachine-websockets) (only Sinatra worked for me)
[em-websocket on GitHub](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-websocket)

UPDATE 1:
this is my main.rb:

```
    require 'rubygems'      # <-- Added this require
require 'em-websocket'
require 'padrino-core'
require 'thin'

require File.expand_path("../config/boot.rb", __FILE__)

SOCKETS = []
EventMachine.run do     # <-- Changed EM to EventMachine
#  class App < Sinatra::Base
#      get '/' do
#          SOCKETS.each {|s| s.send "fooooo"}
#          return "foo"
#      end
#  end

  EventMachine::WebSocket.start(:host => '0.0.0.0', :port => 8080) do |ws| # <-- Added |ws|
      # Websocket code here
      ws.onopen {
          ws.send "connected!!!!"
          SOCKETS << ws
      }

      ws.onmessage { |msg|
          puts "got message #{msg}"
          ws.send "ECHO: #{msg}"
      }

      ws.onclose   {
          ws.send "WebSocket closed"
          SOCKETS.delete ws
      }

  end

  # You could also use Rainbows! instead of Thin.
  # Any EM based Rack handler should do.
  #App.run!({:port => 3000})    # <-- Changed this line from Thin.start to App.run!
  Thin::Server.start Padrino.application, '0.0.0.0', 3000
```

end

i'm getting this exception:

```
/home/cstore/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@runtime/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/daemonizing.rb:2:in `require': no such file to load -- daemons (LoadError)
    from /home/cstore/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@runtime/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/daemonizing.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/cstore/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@runtime/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/server.rb:50:in `<class:Server>'
    from /home/cstore/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@runtime/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/server.rb:48:in `<module:Thin>'
    from /home/cstore/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@runtime/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/server.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from main.rb:39:in `block in <main>'
    from /home/cstore/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@runtime/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `call'
    from /home/cstore/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@runtime/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run_machine'
    from /home/cstore/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@runtime/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run'
    from main.rb:9:in `<main>'
```

UPDATE 2:
Resolved thanks to Nathan !
I just added 'daemons' to Gemfile and reloaded my application.

Comment: Try adding to the Gemfile: `gem 'daemons'` Typically that error means that the gem listed is either not installed to your gemset or not in the Gemfile.

Comment: For reference the line that is generating this exception is simply trying to load the daemons library: https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/blob/v1.2.1/lib/thin/daemonizing.rb#L2

Comment: i added that gem. didn't work.... i just tried again and it worked. God works in mysterious ways :)  THANKS ALOT !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you need to install daemons:

Edit your Gemfile:

```
# Adding this
gem 'daemons'
```

Install missing gems:

```
$ bundle install
```

Comment: Yeah or just try adding to the Gemfile: gem 'daemons' and then run `bundle install`

Answer (score 1):

What in particular from this example: https://github.com/igrigorik/em-websocket and [Any success with Sinatra working together with EventMachine WebSockets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999430/any-success-with-sinatra-working-together-with-eventmachine-websockets) didn't work with Padrino but did with Sinatra? Can you explain the errors you got and why those examples failed (stacktraces)? Maybe we can help investigate.

Answer (score 1):

I ran across this post and it helped me a bit, but I wanted to offer an alternative solution to anyone else who might stumble upon it. I chose to just directly modify the `config.ru` and mount a [websocket-rack](https://github.com/imanel/websocket-rack) application.

Here's my `config.ru` where WSApp is a subclass of `Rack::WebSocket::Application` and is placed in the `lib/` directory (therefore being automatically loaded by Padrino):

```
#!/usr/bin/env rackup
# encoding: utf-8

# This file can be used to start Padrino,
# just execute it from the command line.

require File.expand_path("../config/boot.rb", __FILE__)

# Setup routes
map '/' do
  run Padrino.application
end
map '/ws' do
  run WSApp.new
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is the top hit in Google right now, I'd like to link it to [padrino-websockets](https://github.com/dariocravero/padrino-websockets), a clean DSL for writing websockets applications in Padrino.