# Launching Sinatra inside of an existing EventMachine-powered gem

Tags: ruby, sinatra, eventmachine

Is there a clean way to launch an embedded Sinatra app from within an existing EventMachine loop?  I have a client-server gem (a chatbot) powered by an EM loop and I'd like to spin up an Sinatra admin interface inside of this single running process.  What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Vegas](https://github.com/quirkey/vegas).

It basically lets you fire up any rack application from inside a gem.  It's what the Resque web interface uses.  I've used it myself with [hooves](https://github.com/jstorimer/hooves) (for unicorn support) too.

Comment: This worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999430/any-success-with-sinatra-working-together-with-eventmachine-websockets