# What is a good way to run background processes in foreground for tests in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, rspec, tdd, sinatra, backgroundworker

Working with a Sinatra application, and found 3 ways to run a background process:

1. `Thread.new`
2. `Process.fork`
3. `Process.spawn`

Figured out how to get the first two to work, but now the challenge is that the tests need to run synchronously (for a few reasons).

What is a good way to run jobs asynchronously in production, but force the tests to run synchronously? Preferably with a call in the `spec_helper`...?

Ruby 1.9.3, Sinatra app, RSpec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with:

```
process_in_background { slow_method }

def process_in_background
  Rails.env == 'test' ? yield : Thread.new { yield }
end

def slow_method
  ...code that takes a long time to run...
end
```

I like this solution because it is transparent: it runs ***the exact same code***, just synchronously.

Any suggestions/problems with it?  Is it necessary to manage zombies? How?

Comment: You can also just do `if Rails.env.test?`, but I don't like having these kinds of tests in the code itself, as it clutters up the code (and in the test environment, `process_in_background` doesn't process in the background, so it's a bad method name). A better approach would be to have a couple task processors (e.g. `ThreadBackgroundProcessor` and `ForegroundProcessor`), and configure which one to use based on the environment. That makes it clearer that you don't have tests for the background processing, which may or may not be important.

Comment: Another approach would be to stub out the `process_in_background` method in tests to run the task synchronously. But again, this shouldn't be necessary for unit tests, because unit tests should just test the task itself. For functional/integration tests it might be necessary, but a good architecture will make it not necessary.

Comment: Those are good points. How to choose the thread processor based on the environment without cluttering up the code?

Comment: In rails, I would use an existing framework like delayed_job or resque, but if those didn't fit, I'd add a `config/initializers/background_tasks.rb` that sets up the per-environment configuration. You can do something similar with a pure ruby app, you just have to wire it up into the app's initialization.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the following hybrid approach:

1. Write simple unit tests and refactor what you're testing to be synchronous. In other words, put all of the background functionality into straightforward classes and methods that can be unit tested easily. Then the background processes can call the same functionality, that's already been unit tested. You shouldn't have to unit test the background thread/process creation itself, since this is already tested in ruby (or another library like `god`, `bluepill` or `Daemons`. This TDD approach has the added benefit of making the codebase more maintainable.
2. For functional and integration tests, follow the approach of `delayed_job` and provide a method to do all of the background work synchronously, like with `Delayed::Worker.new.work_off`

You also may want to consider using EventMachine (as in [Any success with Sinatra working together with EventMachine WebSockets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999430/any-success-with-sinatra-working-together-with-eventmachine-websockets) ) over spawning threads or processes, especially if the background processes are IO intensive (making http or database requests, for example).