# How can I use EventMachine from within a Sinatra app?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, eventmachine

I use an api, that is written on top of EM. This means that to make a call, I need to write something like the following:

```
EventMachine.run do
  api.query do |result|
    # Do stuff with result
  end
  EventMachine.stop
end
```

Works fine.

But now I want to use this same API within a Sinatra controller. I tried this:

```
get "/foo" do
  output = ""
  EventMachine.run do
    api.query do |result|
      output = "Result: #{result}"
    end
    EventMachine.stop
  end
  output
end
```

But this doesn't work. The `run` block is bypassed, so an empty response is returned and once `stop` is called, Sinatra shuts down.

Not sure if it's relevant, but my Sinatra app runs on Thin.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3007083/1177119) might be of some help to you.

Comment: see this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999430/any-success-with-sinatra-working-together-with-eventmachine-websockets

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround by busy waiting until data becomes available. Possibly not the best solution, but it works at least:

```
helpers do

  def wait_for(&block)
    while (return_val = block.call).nil?
      sleep(0.1)
    end
    return_val
  end

end

get "/foo" do
  output = nil
  EventMachine.run do
    api.query do |result|
      output = "Result: #{result}"
    end
  end
  wait_for { output }
end
```

Comment: there are libraries for asynchronous request processing in Sinatra. for example https://github.com/raggi/async_sinatra. here is my post on a related subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14993386/async-requests-using-sinatra-streaming-api