# Accessing an EventMachine channel from a Sinatra route

Tags: ruby, websocket, sinatra, eventmachine

I have a simple Sinatra App running on EventMachine, like [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999430/any-success-with-sinatra-working-together-with-eventmachine-websockets).

The app is working, now I'd like to allow the routes I'm defining in Sinatra to access the websocket using the EventMachine channel that is created. I naively tried the following, but of course within the Sinatra App, the `@channel` variable isn't defined, so this doesn't work.

```
require 'em-websocket'
require 'sinatra'

EventMachine.run do
  @channel = EM::Channel.new

  class App < Sinatra::Base
    get '/' do
      erb :index
    end

    post '/test' do
      @channel.push "Post request hit endpoint"
      status 200
    end
  end


  EventMachine::WebSocket.start :host => '0.0.0.0', :port => 8080 do |socket|
    socket.onopen do
      sid = @channel.subscribe { |msg| socket.send msg }
      @channel.push "Subscriber ID #{sid} connected!"

      socket.onmessage do |msg|
        @channel.push "Subscriber <#{sid}> sent message: #{msg}"
      end

      socket.onclose do
        @channel.unsubscribe(sid)
      end
    end
  end

  App.run! :port => 3000
end
```

How could I access the EventMachine channel I've got open within my Sinatra app?

Comment: Have you tried instatiating the EM within a [configure block](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Configuration)? Then you could access it via `settings.channel` (if it works, I'm just suggesting this, I've not tried it).

Comment: @iain the problem with that would be, how to get to it outside of Sinatra then? The only thing I have tried that works is setting this to a global variable, which I suppose is ok but generally frowned upon...

Comment: What about wrapping the whole lot in a module and using a class instance variable of the module? It's scoped and global! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case others don't know what we're talking about in the comments, here's an example of using a class instance variable in the way I suggested. This runs, but I don't know if it does what's expected:

```
require 'em-websocket'
require 'sinatra'
require 'haml'

module Example

  def self.em_channel
    @em_channel ||= EM::Channel.new
  end

  EventMachine.run do

    class App < Sinatra::Base
      configure do
        enable :inline_templates
      end

      get '/' do
        haml :index
      end

      get '/test' do
        Example.em_channel.push "Test request hit endpoint"
        status 200
      end
    end


    EventMachine::WebSocket.start :host => '0.0.0.0', :port => 8080 do |socket|
      socket.onopen do
        sid = Example.em_channel.subscribe { |msg| socket.send msg }
        Example.em_channel.push "Subscriber ID #{sid} connected!"

        socket.onmessage do |msg|
          Example.em_channel.push "Subscriber <#{sid}> sent message: #{msg}"
        end

        socket.onclose do
          Example.em_channel.unsubscribe(sid)
        end
      end
    end

    App.run!
  end
end

__END__

@@ layout
%html
  = yield

@@ index
%div.title Hello world.
```