# How to test a Sinatra method where a websocket is required?

Tags: ruby, websocket, sinatra, minitest

I've just started working with Sinatra and would like to be able to test a method which is checking for a websocket, as in the following snippet:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra-websocket'

set :server, 'thin'
set :sockets, []

get '/' do
    if !request.websocket?
        erb :index
    else
        request.websocket do |ws|
            ws.onopen do
                ws.send("Hello World!")
                settings.sockets << ws
            end
            ws.onmessage do |msg|
                EM.next_tick { settings.sockets.each{|s| s.send(msg) } }
            end
            ws.onclose do
                warn("websocket closed")
                settings.sockets.delete(ws)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

(code lifted from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999430/any-success-with-sinatra-working-together-with-eventmachine-websockets/11944442#11944442) but almost identical to my usage)

I'm using MiniTest for my testing and was hoping there would be a straightforward way to pass in the request using a mock websocket and therefore get beyond the if !request.websocket? conditional.

A snippet with the simplest example would be great but any pointers gratefully received!

Disclaimer: I'm new to Ruby, although am loving it and this may seem obvious although I've not seen any clear examples of use - hence this question!

Comment: My guess would be to look for testing Rack applications. Sinatra uses Rack under the hood and I'm sure that there's probably some information there. Check these out: http://tarynsauer.tumblr.com/post/72337538488/using-rspec-to-test-sinatra-controller  http://patshaughnessy.net/2012/3/7/learning-from-the-masters-sinatra-internals